# How can I fetch data from URL via AJAX or Anything else

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I try to fetch Json object from URL.The following codes doesnt work, They didnt gave me an error or  they didnt return me something 
I can get Json result by viewing url in chrome.So there is no mistake in url name.
Code 1:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = "http://....;  //I cant write url bcz of privacy reasons.
    var getJSON = function (url) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('get', url, true);
            xhr.responseType = 'json';
            xhr.onload = function () {
                var status = xhr.status;
                if (status == 200) {
                    resolve(xhr.response);
                } else {
                    reject(status);
                }
            };
            xhr.send();
        });
    };

    getJSON('http://fantasy.premierleague.com/web/api/elements/100/').then(function (data) {
        alert('Your Json result is:  ' + data.result);
        var o = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
        window.onload = function() {
            // all of your code goes in here
            // it runs after the DOM is built
            // document.getElementById("avengers").innerHTML = o.provider[1].agentID+ " " + o.provider[1].nodeID;
           // document.getElementById('avengers').innerHTML = o.result;
            console.log(o);
        }
        //var names = o.proviver[0].agentID.toString();

        //you can comment this, i used it to debug

    }, function (status) { //error detection....
        alert('Something went wrong.');
    });
    </script>
```

Code 2 :

```html
$.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: '......',
       dataType: 'json',

       success: function(response){
           console.table([response]);
          // $('avengers').append(response.result)
       }
   });
```

Are there any other way. Or I am completely wrong.

Comment: Does it log the response in your second code snippet? What about adding an `error` callback and log the error received, to check if it's a problem with the communication. `error: function (err) { console.error(err) }`

Comment: use `$.getJSON` and read the manual http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: after  alert('Something went wrong.'); add }....

Comment: I add error code now.No i dont get error in log. Just nothing empty.

Comment: When i click empty log in console. I direct me this code console.table([response]);

Comment: I try your code, and i have Access-Control-Origin. and i advise you tu use JQuery for the Asynchronous request!

Comment: It has worked. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
$.post(url,
 data={"key1":value1,"key2":value2,....}, //data={} if nothing to post
 function(data,status)
 {
  if(status=="success")
  {
   console.log(data)
  }
  else
  {
   alert('fail')
  }
}
```